# Compute $1^2 + 3^2+ 5^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2$ by mathematical induction

Tags: summation, induction

I am doing mathematical induction. I am stuck with the question below. The left hand side is not getting equal to the right hand side.
Please guide me how to do it further.

> $1^2 + 3^2+ 5^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}n(2n-1)(2n+1)$.

**Sol:**

$P(n):\ 1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}n(2n-1)(2n+1)$.

For $n=n_1 = 1$

$$P(1) = \frac{1}{3}{3} = (1)^2.$$
Hence it is true for $n=n_0 = 1$.

Let it be true for $n=k$
$$P(k): 1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2k-1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}k(2k-1)(2k+1).$$
We have to prove that it is true for $P(k+1)$.
$$P(k+1) = 1^1+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2k+1)^2 = \frac{1}{3}(k+1)(2k+1)(2k+3)\tag{A}.$$

Taking LHS:
$$\begin{align*}
1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2k+1)^2 &= 1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots + (2k+1)^2\\
&= 1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2k-1)^2 + (2k+1)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{3}k(2k-1)(2k+1) + (2k+1)^2\\
&=\frac{k(2k-1)(2k+1)+3(2k+1)^2}{3}\\
&=\frac{(2k+1)}{3}\left[k(2k-1) + 3(2k+1)\right]\\
&=\frac{(2k+1)}{3}\left[2k^2 - k + 6k + 3\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(2k+1)(2k^2 +5k + 3)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(2k+1)(k+1)\left(k+\frac{3}{2}\right) \tag{B}
\end{align*}$$

EDIT:

Solving EQ (A):

$=(1/3)(2k^2+5K+3) (2K+1) \tag{C}$

Comparing EQ(B) and EQ(C)

Hence proved that it is true for $n = k+1.$

Thus the proposition is true for all $n >= 1$.

Thanks.

Comment: @Arturo: Your answer is more detailed than mine. In a case like this, don't you agree one should write an answer instead of a comment since there's not much more to say and the question is likely to remain unanswered otherwise?

Comment: @joriki: I was kind of hoping the OP might answer his own question once he got the right answer...

Comment: @Arturo: a) Wow, typesetting all that stuff shows true dedication :-). b) When I said your answer is more detailed than mine, I meant that it's more helpful -- why did you remove it?

Comment: I'm with Arturo: since we're allowing people to answer their own questions anyway, it seems to be a good thing to coax people into answering their own questions with appropriate nudges...

Comment: @J. M.: It seems to me that this is based on an unrealistic optimism about how people deal with this site. I see several questions every day that don't get answered because someone wrote the answer in a comment, and I think I have yet to see even one question where the OP answered their own question because someone provided the answer in a comment.

Comment: (+1) ... maybe it'll start a trend of up voting well-posed questions...

Comment: @Gerry: Apparently you just edited the title and this bumped the question to the first page. (1) Do you want this to happen? (2) The new title is incoherent (one does not *prove* a sum).

Comment: @Didier, yes, I just edited the title - please see the thread I started on meta immediately after I made the edit. The sum is in parentheses and my intention was for the title to be read as "Proof by M. I. *involving* $1^2+\dots$". If this offends you, by all means edit it to something better.

Comment: @Gerry: *Offended*? Certainly not. Title modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is OK except for the very last line. You somehow lost a factor of two. The penultimate line is already the result you want, since $2k^2+5k+3=(k+1)(2k+3)$.

Comment: You beat me to it! I think I know how the factor of 2 got `lost': the OP solved the quadratic *equation* $2k^2+5k+3=0$, giving the two *roots* $k=-3/2$ and $k=-1$, which suggests the (incorrect) factorisation $(k+3/2)(k+1)$. The moral of the story is that there is a difference between factorising an expression and solving an equation, even if the two processes are intimately related.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks, I actually used a calculator to solve that and as Shane mentioned it gave the the above results..

Comment: @ShaneORourke: Thanks a lot. I had mostly been solving quadratic equation instead of factorizing them. I think this is the first time it gave different result.

Comment: @Akito: I'm not sure I understand your first comment. You used a calculator to solve what? The quadratic equation that Shane wrote? And it gave which above results? The two roots that Shane wrote? Your statement "it gave the above results" seems to imply that you think there's something about those results, but as Shane explained, it's not those results that are wrong but how you interpreted them and what you did with them.

Comment: @Akito: If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of $ax^2+bx+c$, then $(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ can only equal $ax^2+bx+c$ if $a=1$ (just look at the leading coefficient!). In general, $$(x-r_1)(x-r_2) = x^2 + \frac{b}{a}x + \frac{c}{a}.$$Every time your quadratic is *not* monic, the method you used will fail; you have to keep track of that leading coefficient.

Comment: @joriki: I used the calculator to solve the quadratic equation. It gave the results that Shane had pointed ( k=-3/2 & k=-1 ).

Comment: @Akito: OK -- in that case Shane's and Arturo's comments point to what went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE:  I am not saying anything different, before someone start commenting that my answer is not any different.

$$
\begin{align*}
1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2k+1)^2 &= 1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots + (2k+1)^2\\
&= 1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + (2k-1)^2 + (2k+1)^2\\
&= \frac{1}{3}k(2k-1)(2k+1) + (2k+1)^2\\
&=\frac{k(2k-1)(2k+1)+3(2k+1)^2}{3}\\
&=\frac{(2k+1)}{3}\left[k(2k-1) + 3(2k+1)\right]\\
&=\frac{(2k+1)}{3}\left[2k^2 - k + 6k + 3\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(2k+1)(2k^2 +5k + 3)\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(2k+1) \hspace{3pt}\left[(k+1)(2k+3)\right] \\
&= \frac{1}{3} (k+1)(2(k+1)-1)(2(k+1)+1)
\end{align*}
$$

The last line shows that the result is true for $n=k+1$

Comment: Comment: this answer is not any different.

Comment: So I guess you did not read my NOTE: I am not saying anything different, before someone start commenting that my answer is not any different.

Comment: I did. $ $ $ $ $ $