# Calculate sum of squares of first $n$ odd numbers

Tags: summation

Is there an analytical expression for the summation $$1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2,$$ and how do you derive it?

Comment: http://www.9math.com/book/sum-squares-first-n-odd-natural-numbers

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72636/compute-12-32-52-cdots-2n-12-by-mathematical-induction)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

$$ 1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(4i^2)- \sum_{i=1}^{n}(4i) + \sum_{1}^{n}1=\dots.$$

Now, you need the [identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation)

> > $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}1 = n, $$
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^{n}i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}, $$
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \frac{n^3}{3} + \frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{6}.$$

Comment: +1 This answer is simpler to calculate than the binomial coefficient.

Comment: @user117 Manetheran. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 20):

The following is a very general technique. In particular, it's probably not the best way to solve this sort of problem in the beginning. But it is worth knowing this technique in the long run.

We use the result that:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{k}{i} = \binom{n}{i+1}$$

Write: $$(2k+1)^2=8\binom{k}{2} +8\binom{k}{1}+ \binom{k}{0}$$ Then $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (2k+1)^2 &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left( 8\binom{k}{2} + 8\binom{k}{1} + \binom{k}{0}\right)\\&=8\binom{n}{3}+8\binom{n}{2} + \binom{n}{1}\end{align}$$

This method can be used to solve $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} p(k)$ for any polynomial $p$. The result is always a polynomial of one degree higher than the degree of $p$.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you please explain a little more what does this bracket notation mean?

Comment: Ah, if you don't know the "binomial coefficient," then this will seem mysterious. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Do you have a link (without induction) of the first result?

Comment: @IanMateus That's a pretty common result, but I'm not sure the best place for it. The right hand side counts subsets of size $i+1$ of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, while the the $k$th term counts the same subsets where the largest element is $k+1$. It's also pretty easy to prove via induction on $n$...

Comment: Found it on Wikipedia. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

One can give a combinatorial version of the argument below. But it takes some time to tell the right story. So for now we settle for the magic math  approach. We have
$$\binom{2k+1}{3}-\binom{2k-1}{3}=\frac{(2k+1)(2k)(2k-1)-(2k-1)(2k-2)(2k-3)}{3!}.\tag{1}$$
Note that the above equation even holds when $k=1$, if we use the convention that $\binom{1}{3}=0$.

The right-hand side of (1) magically simplifies to $(2k-1)^2$.   It follows that our sum $1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots +(2n-1)^2$ is equal to
$$ \binom{3}{3}-\binom{1}{3}   + 
 \binom{5}{3}-\binom{3}{3}  + \binom{7}{3}-\binom{5}{3}  +  \cdots + \binom{2n+1}{3}-\binom{2n-1}{3}  .$$ 
Note the wholesale cancellation. We get
$$1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots +(2n-1)^2=\binom{2n+1}{3}.$$

Comment: Kind of working backwards, but still nice. I suppose this would be "obvious" if we realized that $k^2=\binom{k}{2}+\binom{k+1}{2}$.

Comment: There are various combinatorial ways to show that the sum is indeed $\binom{2n+1}{3}$. Here is a cute thing you might like. The formula for the sum of the first $n$ squares is kind of strange, with that weird $2n+1$. Actually, it is $n$ and $n+1$ that are weird. One can use a combinatorial argument to show that the sum is $\frac{1}{4}\binom{2n+2}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: $1^2+2^2+3^2+...+k^2=k(k+1)(2k+1)/6$.

Comment: Did you mean 3 to the 2nd power instead of 3 to the 3rd power?

Comment: Thank you, I think I'm getting close.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood: Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1² + 3² + 5² + ...

Tn = [1 + (n – 1)(2)]²
= (2n – 1)² = 4n² – 4n + 1

Total sum = ∑4n² – ∑4n + n

= 4n(n + 1)(2n+1)/6 – 4n(n + 1)/2 + n

= 2n(n + 1)(2n+1)/3 – 2n(n + 1) + n

= 2n[(n + 1)(2n+1)/3 – 1] + n

= 2n[(n + 1)(2n + 1 – 3/3] + n

= 2n[(n + 1)(2n – 2/3] + n

= 4n[(n + 1)(n – 1/3] + n

= 4n[(n + 1)(n – 1 + 3n]/3

### = n(2n + 1)(2n – 1)/3