# can use diagonal matrix in a formula to figure out how many characters would occur in all substrings of a string 's'?

Tags: matrices, asymptotics

Math experts -

I'm working through a simple "big O" analysis of algorithms problem comparing
two approaches to the longest substring problem. One approach is brute force:
checking all possible substrings and selecting the longest.

I wanted to quantify the complexity of this approach in terms of character compares.
So I need a formula to figure out how many characters would occur in all substrings of a
string "s".

Suppose the target string is 'mouse' and the string to check is "house" (in which case
the answer is "ouse"), then all the substrings to check would be

```
house   ouse     use  se    e
hous    ous      us   s
hou     ou       u
ho      o
h
```

Which seems to inidicate that the formula would involve summing all the cells 
of a diagonal matrix, whose columns are given by the formula:

```
n       n-1     n-2     ...         1
n-1     n-2     n-3
n-2     n-3     n-4
n-3
.
.
.
1
```

I'm guessing this is solveable by some kind of series matrix sum thingee.. But my linear algebra 
is a bit  of a work-in-progress.  Any advice or tips much appreciated.

thanks
/ Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first column, we have the sum of numbers from $1$ to $n$, for the second column the sum from $1$ to $n-1$, and so on. The summation of all the cells of the matrix will be
$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{m=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^mk\\&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{(n-1)n}{2}+\cdots +1\\&=n^2+(n-2)^2+(n-4)^2+\cdots+1\end{align}$$
We have a sum of squares, of either odd or even numbers. Thus, two cases need to be considered: when $n$ is even, and when $n$ is odd.

For the even case we have
$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{m=0}^{(n/2)-1}(n-2m)^2\\&=\sum_{m=0}^{(n/2)-1}n^2-4n\sum_{m=0}^{(n/2)-1}m+4\sum_{m=0}^{(n/2)-1}m^2\\&=\frac{n^3}{2}-\frac{n^2(n-2)}{2}+4\left(\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)^3}{3}+\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)^2}{2}+\frac{\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)}{6}\right)\end{align}$$
As regards the odd case, the formula is
$$\begin{align}S&=\sum_{m=0}^{(n-1)/2}(n-2m)^2\\&=\sum_{m=0}^{(n-1)/2}n^2-4n\sum_{m=0}^{(n-1)/2}m+4\sum_{m=0}^{(n-1)/2}m^2\\&=\frac{(n+1)n^2}{2}-\frac{n(n^2-1)}{2}+4\left(\frac{\left(n-1\right)^3}{24}+\frac{\left(n-1\right)^2}{8}+\frac{\left(n-1\right)}{12}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Really cool !  with a little refresher on series from Mr. Khan ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VgVJrSJxkDk )  I understood it.

Comment: Actually.. i did have one last question...  I looked up 'sum of squares formula' and found >  [ n(n+1)(2n+1) ] / 6     But you have a series  that goes:     n^2 + (n-2)^2 + (n-4)^2 ... +1     -    This is like sum of squares with some numbers skipped.  Is there some tutorial on how the formula for this is derived ?

Comment: There is quite a nice answer to the sum of squares for the odd numbers, which can be found here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437835/calculate-sum-of-squares-of-first-n-odd-numbers

Comment: Very helpful... now, I double promise, this will be the last question.  i've almost got it all in my head  ;^)   --   Is there perhaps a bug in the Sigma sum for the odd and the even case.  I think in both cases the limit should be  (n-1)/2 ... however you use different limits in the odd and even case  (n/2 -1  in the latter).      Thanks again !    - cb

Comment: Feel free to ask questions, if it helps clarify things. Now, for when $n$ is even, we have $n/2$ pairs of consecutive square of even terms to add, $\frac{1}{2}(n(n+1)+(n-1)(n))=n^2$, down to $[n-2(n/2-1)]^2$. Starting from index $0$, the final index will be $(n/2)-1$. For the odd case, we have $(n-1)/2$ pairs, and a final single value, so we need to add $((n-1)/2)+1$ terms. Starting from index $0$, our limit will be $(n-1)/2$, for the odd case.

Comment: got it !  thanks again ;^)