# Prove that $1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2 = (4n^3-n)/3$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction

Prove that $1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2 = (4n^3-n)/3$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I solve this with induction? I've been working through a couple examples and for this one I can't relate the base case to the induction hypothesis.

I realize the base case is $n = 1$, which I check by putting $n = 1$ directly into $(4n^3-n)/3$ and $(2n-1)^2$, which proves the base case.

Then I tried to compose the last two terms of the sequence by: $\cdots + (2k-3)^2 + (2k-1)^2$. Am I approaching this correctly? How would I do this? A solution would be helpful as I've tried many other things such as expanding, making an inequality, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: At least connect this to an even [older post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72636) that is a target of several duplicate posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induction step is just a matter of assuming that

$$1^2+3^2+5^2+\ldots+(2k-1)^2=\frac{4k^3-k}3$$

and proving that

$$1^2+3^2+5^2+\ldots+(2k-1)^2+\big(2(k+1)-1\big)^2=\frac{4(k+1)^3-(k+1)}3\;,$$

i.e., that

$$1^2+3^2+5^2+\ldots+(2k-1)^2+(2k+1)^2=\frac{4(k+1)^3-(k+1)}3\;.\tag{1}$$

By the induction hypothesis the lefthand side of $(1)$ is equal to

$$\frac{4k^3-k}3+(2k+1)^2\;,\tag{2}$$

so you need only do the algebra necessary to show that $(2)$ is equal to the righthand side of $(1)$.

Comment: why did you add $(4k^3 -k)/3$ to the left side?

Comment: @Mac: I didn’t. I used the induction hypothesis to replace $$1^2+3^2+\ldots+(2k-1)^2$$ by $$\frac{4k^3-k}3\;.$$

Comment: I tried algebraically and I don't follow... I must be stupid

Comment: @Mac: $(2)$ in my answer expands to $$\frac{4k^3-k}3+4k^2+4k+1=\frac{4k^3-k+12k^2+12k+3}3=\frac{4k^3+12k^2+11k+3}3$$ The righthand side of $(1)$ expands to $$\frac{4k^3+12k^2+12k+4-k-1}3=\frac{4k^3+12k^2+11k+3}3\;,$$ which is the same.

Comment: thank you I got it after, btw i think you mean 3 instead of 1 on your expression for the left side.

Comment: @Mac: You’re welcome. Yes, I did indeed mean $3$, and thanks to your comment, I caught it in time to edit my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the equation you displayed is correct for $n$.  Add $(2(n+1)-1)^2$ to both sides.  Show that the right-hand side equals $(4(n+1)^3-(n+1))/3$.