# Find the sum of the series $1^2 + 3^2 + 5^2 +\ldots+ (2n – 1)^2$

Tags: summation

> Find the sum of the series $1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$

It is a mathematical question and I can't get it answer. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: Do you know the formula for a sum of consecutive squares? Sum all squares up to $(2n)^2$ and subtract teh even ones -- namely $2^2$ times the sum of _all_ squares up to $n^2$.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate.

Comment: Write out the first few values. Guess the general form. Prove it by induction.

Comment: Henning's comment gives: $$\begin{align}1^2+2^2+\cdots+(2n)^2 &= [1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2] + [2^2+4^2+\cdots+(2n)^2] \\ 
& = [1^2+3^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2] + 2^2 [1^2+2^2+\cdots+n^2]\end{align}$$

Comment: @A---B Here are a few duplicate targets (there must be more). Pick your favorite, ordered chronologically, newest first: [2230785](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230785), [533827](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533827), [437835](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437835), and 7-year-old [72636](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72636).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compute $1^2 + 3^2+ 5^2 + \cdots + (2n-1)^2$ by mathematical induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72636/compute-12-32-52-cdots-2n-12-by-mathematical-induction)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Notice We can write your sum as

$$ S = \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = \sum_i (4i^2 - 4i + 1) = 4 \sum_i i^2 - 4 \sum_i i + n$$

Answer (score 1):

These formulas may help you: $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^2=\frac {n (n+1)(2n+1)}{6} $$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k=\frac {n (n+1)}{2} $$
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c=cn$$
Your result should then be something like $$\frac {(2n-1)2n (2n+1)}{6} $$

Comment: Please add $\sum k = n(n+1)/2$ and $\sum c = nc$ also.

Answer (score 0):

Using [finite calculus](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf) we can sum polynomials using what's called *falling powers*:

\begin{align}
    \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} (2x+1)^2
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} (4x^2+4x+1) 
  = \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} [4x(x-1) + 8x + 1] \\
 &= \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} [4x^{\underline2} + 8x^{\underline1} + 1]
  = \left.\frac{4}{3}x^{\underline3}+4x^{\underline2}+x^{\underline1}\right|_{0}^{n} \\
 &= \left.\frac{4}{3}x(x-1)(x-2)+4x(x-1)+x\right|_{0}^{n} \\
 &= \frac{4}{3}n(n-1)(n-2)+4n(n-1)+n \\ 
 &= \frac{n}{3}(4n^2-1).
\end{align}