# Find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 1^2+3^2+....+(2n-1)^2$

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 1^2+3^2+...+(2n-1)^2.$$

I want to find a closed formula for this sum, however I'm not sure how to do this. I don't mind if you don't give me the answer but it would be much appreciated. I would rather have a link or anything that helps me understand to get to the answer.

EDIT: I Found this question in a calculus book so I don't really know which tag it should be.

Comment: The statement itself is wrong to begin with. $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2 = 1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2$.

Comment: hmm..what do you mean?

Comment: (2n-1) is odd integer if n is integer.

Comment: Also, it should end on $(2n-1)^2$ and not $(2i-1)^2$ which makes no sense.

Comment: What @DHMO is saying is that $i$ is defined only within the sum.  Therefore, it can't appear on the RHS.  Instead, the RHS should have only the variable $n$.

Comment: Everyone cared about the last term. Only @samjoe noticed that the middle terms are also wrong.

Comment: @DHMO: I noticed, that's why I said "also" ;)

Comment: @DHMO: I think you should edit the question, the mistakes are still there after a couple of edits.

Comment: @Mathematician42 you can edit the question.

Comment: Just realized all the mistakes I made ugh. This is the result of lack of sleep and too much coffee. Ty for editing the mistakes.

Comment: At least connect this to an [old post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72636) that is a target of several duplicate posts.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. And last but not least $$(2i-1)^2=4i^2-4i+1.$$

Edit: Let's prove that $\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. We proceed by induction on $n$. If $n=1$ the statement is trivial. Now suppose the statement holds for $n\geq 1$. Then \begin{eqnarray}\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}i&=&\sum_{i=1}^ni+(n+1)\\
&=&\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+(n+1)\\
&=& (n+1)(\frac{n}{2}+1)\\
&=& \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}.\end{eqnarray}
Here we used the induction hypothesis in the second equation. This proves the statement by induction. You can prove the other formula in a similar fashion.

Comment: $\frac{4n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{4n(n+1)}{2} + n$ will it look something like this? and where can i learn about these formulas etc.

Comment: Yes, if you work it out you should get $\frac{1}{3}n(4n^2-1).$ I'll edit my answer and show you how to prove one the formulas.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

We have

$$1^2+3^2+5^2+... (2n-1)^2=$$

$=\sum $ odd$^2$=$\sum$ all$^2 $-$\sum $even$^2=$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2-(2^2+4^2+...4n^2)= $$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k^2-4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=$$

$$\boxed {\color {green}{\frac {n(4n^2-1)}{3}}}$$

for $n=2$, we have $10 $ , for $n=3$, we find $35$ and for $n=4$, it is $84$.

Comment: i don't understand how you got to $\sum_1^{2n} k^2-(2^2+4^2+...4n^2)=$

Comment: plus what does $\sum_1^{2n} $ this even mean. How can it be 2n isnt it essentially just n

Comment: @TomHarry I edited it . now it is clear.

Comment: doesn't sigma all^2 = $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2$ and if so why do u have $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} k^2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2$. You can start by hypothesizing that the sum of squares is a cubic $f(n) = an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d$ (as a sort of discrete analogy with the integration formula $\int x^2\, dx = x^3/3 + C$). Then $(2n+1)^2 = f(n+1) - f(n) = a (3n^2 + 3n + 1) + b(2n + 1) + c$, which gets you the constants $a, b, c$, and you can find $d$ from $f(1) = 1$. Verifying this formula is an easy proof by induction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1)^2
&=\sum_{i=1}^n \binom {2i-1}2+\binom {2i}2&&\text(*)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{2n}\binom r2\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{r=2}^{2n}\binom r2}\\
&=\color{red}{\binom {2n+1}3}&& \text(**)\\
&\color{lightgrey}{=\frac {(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)}6}\\
&\color{lightgrey}{=\frac 13 n(2n-1)(2n+1)}\\
&\color{lightgrey}{=\frac 13 n(4n^2-1)}
\end{align}$$

---

*Note that   $\;\;\;R^2=\binom R2+\binom {R+1}2$.
**Using the [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)

Answer (score 0):

There has grneral method,no longer requires various skills.See [Redefining the Shape of Numbers and Three Forms of Calculation](https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=108030)

define:

$$SUM(N,[{K_1},{K_2}...{K_M}]:D,[1,2...M]) = \sum\limits_{i = 0}^{N - 1} {({K_1} + nD)} ({K_2} + nD)...({K_M} + nD)$$
then
$$SUM(N,[{K_1},{K_2}...{K_M}]:D,[1,2...M]) = \sum\limits_{g = 0}^M {{H_1}} (g)\left( {_{g + 1}^N} \right)$$
Use an auxiliary form for calculating H<sub>1</sub>(g).
$$SET - T = \{ {T_1},{T_2}....{T_M}\}  = \{ 1,2...M\} ,SET - K = \{ {K_1},{K_2}....{K_M}\} $$
$$({K_1} + {T_1})({K_2} + {T_2})...({K_M} + {T_M})  = \sum {\coprod\limits_{i = 1}^M {{X_i}} } ,{X_i} = {T_i}\,or\,\,{K_i}$$
Define:
$$X(T) = count{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} of{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {X_i} \in SET-T $$
$${X_{T - 1}} = count{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} of\{ {X_1},{X_2}...{X_{i - 1}}\}  \in \{ {T_1},{T_2}...{T_{i - 1}}\} $$
$${X_{K - 1}} = count{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} of\{ {X_1},{X_2}...{X_{i - 1}}\}  \in \{ {K_1},{K_2}...{K_{i - 1}}\} $$
$${X_{T - 1}} + {X_{K - 1}} = i - 1$$
Each ∏X<sub>i</sub> corresponds to one expression in the sum.
$${H_1}(g) = \sum\limits_{X(T) = g} {\prod\limits_{i = 1}^M {{B_i}} } .If\,{X_i} = {T_i}{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} then{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {B_i} = ({T_i} - {X_{K - 1}})D{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} else{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {B_i} = {K_i} + {X_{T - 1}}D$$

---

In this question:

$${\text{SUM(n ,[1,1]:2,[1,2])}} = {H_1}(2)\left( {_3^n} \right) + {H_1}(1)\left( {_2^n} \right) + {H_1}(0)\left( {_1^n} \right)$$
$$Form:({K_1} + {T_1})({K_2} + {T_2}) = {K_1}{K_2} + {K_1}{T_2} + {T_1}{K_2} + {T_1}{T_2},don't{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} swap{\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} {\kern 1pt} factors$$

$$\sum\limits_{X(T) = 1} {\prod {{B_i}} }  = {T_1}{K_2} + {K_1}{T_2},{H_1}(1) = 1 \times D \times (1 + D \times {X_{T - 1}}) + 1 \times (2 - {X_{{\text{K}} - 1}}) \times {\text{D}}$$  $$\to {H_1}(1) = 1 \times 2 \times (1 + 2) + 1 \times (2 - 1) \times 2 = 8$$

$${H_1}(0) = 1 \times 1 = 1,{H_1}(2) = 2!{2^2} = 8$$
$$Answer = 8\left( {_3^n} \right) + 8\left( {_2^n} \right) + \left( {_1^n} \right) = \frac{{n(4{n^2} - 1)}}{3}$$

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1988287)

Comment: The simplest description has been added